# Advice needed: Project Structure for Namespaced App Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I am developing an app that has two name spaced differentiated folders.

Lets say

`App/Http/Users/` and
`App/Http/Drivers/`

I have two api routes setup `api.php` and `dapi.php`.
The routes are also prefixed by `localhost/api/foo` and `localhost/dapi/bar` respectively.

Everything works ok but the issue is that there are some methods that I need to call for both. Such as save address info or call. Right now I have to make same controllers for both and duplicate a lot of code. What would be the best approach for this kind of project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

> Traits are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages
>   such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single
>   inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in
>   several independent classes living in different class hierarchies. The
>   semantics of the combination of Traits and classes is defined in a way
>   which reduces complexity, and avoids the typical problems associated
>   with multiple inheritance and Mixins.

for example:

in your traite:

```
    trait SameMethods {
        function call() { /*1*/ }
        function saveAddress() { /*2*/ }
    }
```

.

```
namespace App\Http\Drivers;

        class Foo extends Controller{
            use SameMethods ;
            /* ... */
        }
```

.

```
namespace App\Http\Users;

        class Bar extends Controller{
            use SameMethods ;
            /* ... */
        }
```

Now you have these methods on your controllers.

another way is you have an another class for example ParentController extended from Controller that it contains same methods and foo and bar extends from this class

```
ParentController extends Controller {
    function call() { /*1*/ }
    function saveAddress() { /*2*/ }
}
```

.

```
namespace App\Http\Drivers;

        class Foo extends ParentController {

            /* ... */
        }
```

.

```
namespace App\Http\Users;

        class Bar extends ParentController {

            /* ... */
        }
```

Comment: Ah ok. I have to use separate controllers for swagger and stuff but traits worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you